# Transferring large amounts of data to Activity using putExtra();

Tags: android, json, android-intent

The application passes large number of objects (about 150 objects after parsing `JSON` format) via `intent.putExtra();`
Among them are `serialized` objects.
And the process of opening a new activity takes about 2 seconds...
Is there a way to speed up this process?

Comment: if you pass data inside your app and data is large then do not use intent. Create a storage in Application claas. Google "android sharing data between activities".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to pass data from one activity to another you can just use a static variable that is accessible from both activities. This eliminates the need to serialize and deserialize all the objects. Example:

```
public class Globals {
    public static List<MyObject> myObjects;
}
```

In one activity you can set the data you want to pass in `Globals.myObjects` and the receiving activity can get it from there.

Be aware that this mechanism does have some drawbacks (like when Android kills your process and restarts it later). However, this can be the least troublesome way to simply hand a lot of objects from one activity to another.

Comment: Thanks! This is the simplest way for me!

Comment: when I am using a singleton class to pass values to a`'Page Adapter` I get a  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 101, found: 200` error

Comment: @viper Please open a new question for this problem. Adding your problem here as a comment isn't the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion could be:

*Use [parceable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) where you are using serializable*

Another suggestion could be:

*Use something else to save/restore the data. e.g. a database*

Comment: _Use parceable where you are using serializable_
I have a complex set of data - does not approach.
_Use something else to save/restore the data. e.g. a database_
This makes double work...
_Use a wrapper object for al your objects, this lowers the amount of functions called_
By time there is no difference at all.

The solution is using global static wrapper as said David Wasser

Comment: this is not the android way, it could fail in some scenarios. Also the easiest way out is not the best way out

Comment: Perhaps, but for now it is the fastest solution to the problem. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think using a **Singleton** class for sharing large amount of temporary data between activities is a great way to go. Keeps it really quick and simple.

Although it can be done through Android **Parcelable** but it has storage limitation which can cause this error **"!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!"**